# Output string after certain character is met

Tags: c#, .net

so what im doing currently is
getting the text from a file i.e a .txt
and putting it into an array i.e
whilst comparing the two files and outputting the differences between a and B

```cs
     string[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(path\file.txt);
     string[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(path\file2.txt);
     IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Except(linesA);
     string[] newstr = new HashSet<string>(onlyB).ToArray();
     File.WriteAllLines('C:\path\', newstr);
```

and lets say the text inside the files includes : i.e

```
    file a:
    code(324332): 65dfsdf4fth
    code(32342): hdfgvsdfsdgh
    code(323462): h29dfs8dh

    file b:

    code(324332): 65dfsdf4fth
    code(32342): hdfgvsdfsdgh
    code(323462): h29dfs8dh
    code(453453): 8gbhfhk,jv
    code(343435): gigdbioyvgi
    code(3435343): guidfyvfhs
```

how would i go about getting the text after **:**
and removing duplicates

so in the end the output would be

```
8gbhfhk,jv
gigdbioyvgi
guidfyvfhs
```

edited:

Kind regards,
Phil

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question.  What is your goal? What is your problem? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your problem and share more code.  To help you improve the content, title and tags of your question, consider the reading of the *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* which is in the help center.

Comment: You can use String.Split((char)3232)[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text after `:` you can use the `Substring` and `IndexOf` methods, then remove the whitespace at the beginning of your new string with `TrimStart`. At the end use `Concat` to combine the two lists and `GroupBy` to filter out the values that have duplicates:

```
string[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");
string[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file2.txt");

IEnumerable<string> linesA2 = linesA.Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(":") + 1).TrimStart());

IEnumerable<string> linesB2 = linesB.Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(":") + 1).TrimStart());

string[] result = linesA2.Concat(linesB2).GroupBy(x => x)
                                         .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                                         .Select(y => y.Key)
                                         .ToArray();
```

**result:**

```
result[0] ="8gbhfhk,jv"

result[1] ="gigdbioyvgi"

result[2] ="guidfyvfhs"
```

Write the result array to new text file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\file3.txt", result);
```

Comment: and how would i go about outputting every single thing in the array along with deleting duplicates in that array

Comment: The `result` array holds you desired output, just write the `result` array to new text file with `File.WriteAllLines`

Comment: Thank you!

The lines 2 methods pointed me in the right directions!

Answer (score 1):

You can browse files and registrars row by row in a list of type "Dictionary  .Add (TKey, TValue)" so that you only have the unique values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=netframework-4.8